# UserTransactionAdapter vs UserTransactionImpl

Tags: java, spring, jboss7.x, jta

Does spring contain a jta implementation ?

I see that class [UserTransactionAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/jta/UserTransactionAdapter.html) implements [UserTransaction](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/transaction/UserTransaction.html) but javax.transaction.UserTransaction don't exists in any spring jar.

In the other hand javax.transaction.UserTransaction exist in jboss runtime library but the implementation is in spring jar. And another UserTransaction (from jbossxts-4.17.21.Final-redhat-2.jar) implementation: UserTransactionImpl can be found in jbossxts-4.17.21.Final-redhat-2.jar in jboss modules folder.

Can someone explain this to me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Spring doesn't have it's own **JTA implementation**. It has it's own transaction management infrastructure which is *independent* of the JTA API, but it has an implementation of his own TransactionManager API, which can use (delegate to) a JTA `TransactionManager`. There are other implementations for his own transaction API such as Hibernate-, JDO-, JPA-, DataSource, but they all delegate the transaction management work to the underlying transaction infrastructure. To sum up, you can use the Spring transaction management infrastructure in your app and delegate to a JTA `TransactionManager` if there's any in your environment, but Spring itself doesn't provide a JTA `TransactionManager` implementation.

Spring's implementation of `UserTransaction` in it's `UserTransactionAdapter` class is only there to adapt the JTA `TransactionManager` to the `UserTransaction` interface, because, while `UserTransaction` is an exact subset of the `TransactionManager` interface, the `TransactionManager` interface itself doesn't extend the `UserTransaction` interface. Consider it only as a simple helper class, it doesn't do anything besides adapting one interface to another.

Answer (score 1):

> Does spring contains a jta implementation ?

No.

> I see that class UserTransactionAdapter implements UserTransaction but javax.transaction.UserTransaction don't exists in any spring jar.

`javax.transaction.UserTransaction` is an element of the JTA specification, in other words it is a standard API. There is no reason for Spring to include it.

> In the other hand javax.transaction.UserTransaction exists in jboss runtime library

Indeed, because JBoss is a JEE compliant application server and so it include the JEE standard libs (JTA, JPA, JMS, ...)

> but the implementation is in a Spring jar.

It is just a syntaxic sugar to map UserTransaction to TransactionManager, and it is [not intended for direct use in application code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-tx/4.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/transaction/jta/UserTransactionAdapter.java#27).

> And another UserTransaction (from jbossxts-4.17.21.Final-redhat-2.jar) implementation: UserTransactionImpl can be found in jbossxts-4.17.21.Final-redhat-2.jar in jboss modules folder.

As JBoss implements the JTA specification: it is the jboss implementation of UserTransaction standard API.

> Can someone explain this to me ?

Spring provides a uniform API to deal with different transaction managers in a very simple way. You just have to say to Spring to use implementation X or Y in a configuration. At the end, spring **delegates** the *real* transaction management to the implementation that you choose. (and to perform this delegation, it appears that in some scenarios the syntaxic sugar 'UserTransactionAdapter' is required internally by Spring)